# jquery click event only works once

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I've been researching this all morning and am missing something.

Here is the basic setup and code:

```
<script  src="/mwebphoto/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow">
</div>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="gallery_id">
 <li id="newYork">New York</li>
 <li id="disconnection">Disconnexion</li>
 <li id="jackAtSea">Jack at Sea</li>
</ul>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#gallery_id li").click(function () {
          var htmlTitle = (this.id);

          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/mwebphoto/xml/albums.xml",
              dataType: "xml",
              success: function (xml) {
                  $(xml).find('album').each(function () {
                      var xmlAlbum = $(this);
                      var xmlTitle = $(this).find('title').text();
                      var xmlEmbedCode = $(this).find('embedCode').text();
                        if (xmlTitle == htmlTitle) 
                          alert(xmlTitle)
                          $("#slideshow").replaceWith(xmlTitle)

                  });
              }
          });
      });

  });
</script>
```

(note, I've edited this in response to the answers, starting here)

I believe the problem is here:

```
if(xmlTitle==htmlTitle) 
  alert(xmlTitle) 
  $("#slideshow").replaceWith(xmlTitle)
```

The alert works fine. But the .replaceWith puts the second li (disconnection) in the div no matter which list item I click.

You can see here: http://mwebphoto.com/mwebphoto/html/2ndJqueryPage.html

Comment: What does it do now, and what should it do instead?

Comment: From a semantic point of view, assuming clicking the list items alters some content, they should probably contain anchor tags.

Comment: Are you replacing your click target element when you run the ajax callback? That would kill your click handler.

Comment: Have you tried this instead ? `$(document).on('click','#gallery_id li',function(e){...` Cause actually you are binding the handler to every li elements inside #gallery_id li, but you have none.

Comment: Do you really have a `<div>` within the `<head>` tag? I'm thinking that's invalid html.

Comment: I updated my entry to narrow the problem, which seems to be with the .replaceWith() function.

Now it puts the second list item in the div no matter which item is clicked, even though the alert works correctly. As currently set up, it should come back with an xml title match for the id on the list item. You can see at http://mwebphoto.com/mwebphoto/html/2ndJqueryPage.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#gallery_id li").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
       //represents li within li
  });
```

it should be either

```
$("#gallery_id li").on('click', function(e) {
       alert(this.id);
  });
```

or

```
$("#gallery_id").on('click','li', function () {
         alert(this.id);
     })
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#gallery_id li', function () {
         alert(this.id);
     })
```

Try this.

**Updates:**

To show the difference, I have created

1. [**Your Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkFch/1/)
2. [**Correct Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkFch/)

Hope you find the differences.

Comment: I believe the problem is here:

    if(xmlTitle==htmlTitle)
       $("#slideshow").replaceWith(xmlTitle)
       
       alert(xmlTitle)

The alert works fine if the .replaceWith is commented. But when the .replaceWith is active, the alert loops through all three options, then I am unable to click again.

Comment: Ignore last reply. Here's the situation:

I believe the problem is here: 

    if(xmlTitle==htmlTitle) 
      alert(xmlTitle) 
      $("#slideshow").replaceWith(xmlTitle) 
      
The alert works fine. But the .replaceWith puts the second <li> (disconnection) in the <div> no matter which list item I click.

Comment: @mweb202 can you share the xml file?  what is this ` $(xml)`

Comment: xml file is here: http://mwebphoto.com/mwebphoto/xml/albums.xml. The `$(xml)` part finds the children of node "album". That part seems to be working correctly. Here is the link to a test page:  http://mwebphoto.com/mwebphoto/html/2ndJqueryPage.html

Answer (score 0):

If your html is

```
<ul id="gallery_id">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Try with this code. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.

```
 $("#gallery_id").on('click','li', function () {
         // your code
     })
```